# How to load a new page in pop windows SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, development, popup

I have created a custom page and configured it as a Display form on SharePoint list. All the list forms are configured to Launch as a Dialog.'

Now I want my users to see a different page within the popup window upon clicking on a button on Display Form.

Please advise.

I have tried `window.redirect`, `response.redirect`, `$.ajax POST`. None of these worked.

Comment: I resolved this myself by replacing button with hyperlink and adding href to it dynamically.
<a class="button k-button" target="_self" id="Edit">Edit</a>




$('#Edit').attr('href', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/EditForm?ID="+ID);

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ModalDialog` to open a link as **popup window**,

- Edit your display form.

[image]

- Add Script Editor web part > Edit Snippet.
- Add the below code with your Link.

**ModalDialog Code**

```
<script>
function openDialog(pageUrl) {
var options = {
url: pageUrl,
title: 'Title of the Dialog',
allowMaximize: false,
showClose: true,
width: 500,
height: 500
};
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('http://siteURL');">Link</a>
```

For the details steps check [Open a link via Modal Dialog in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/13/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)

Comment: As I mentioned, this is my custom aspx application display page. which I am already loading as a modal dialog. I want the page within the  modal dialog to be redirected to a new page upon a button click.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this myself by replacing button with hyperlink and adding href to it dynamically.

```
<a class="button k-button" target="_self" id="Edit">Edit</a> 

$('#Edit').attr('href', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
"/_layouts/15/EditForm?ID="+ID);
```